# Exchange 2016 - hostnames of client computers

Tags: exchange

Is it possible to find out the names of computers that connect to the mail server?
Clients work through Outlook and the web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check users connected in Cached mode or online mode through RPC Client Access Logs. Or use the exmon tool. You can download it from here.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11461

Refer to below document for your reference.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28446.exchange-determining-the-list-of-users-connected-in-outlook-onlinecached-mode.aspx